# How to get video streams in a program?

Tags: python, download

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stream large binary files with urllib2 to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517616/stream-large-binary-files-with-urllib2-to-file)

I want to make a video downloader which when given the url of a page which has a video to stream can download the video.

So what i thought was if i get the video stream, i can copy the content into a string and then copy it into file .
How can i do it in python?Is there any library in python which can help?

Answer (score 0):

for python 2.x

[urllib](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html)

Use method urlretrieve

Comment: it is used if the url denotes a file while in video streaming it is diffrent from what i understood..

Comment: The second argument, if present, specifies the file location to copy to (if absent, the location will be a tempfile with a generated name). The third argument, if present, is a hook function that will be called once on establishment of the network connection and once after each block read thereafter. The hook will be passed three arguments; a count of blocks transferred so far, a block size in bytes, and the total size of the file. The third argument may be -1 on older FTP servers which do not return a file size in response to a retrieval request.

http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html