# Python download file without external library

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a very large Python script that I am using pyinstaller with to create an exe. I need to download an XML file but would like to keep the exe as small as possible as it is already getting quite large.

Is there a method within Python to get a file from a URL? I was not able to find anything without an external library

Comment: Keep this under your pillow: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22676/how-do-i-download-a-file-over-http-using-python

Comment: related: [Stream large binary files with urllib2 to file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1517616/4279)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [urllib.urlretrieve()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) that saves the opened page to the specified path.

Alternatively you can open the url with [urllib.urlopen()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlopen) and then write the read file in the binary mode:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve(url, destination_path) # First and short way

with open(destination_path, 'wb') as f:   # Equivalent to the first, but longer
    f.write(urllib.urlopen(url).read())
```

Comment: In Python 3, these functions have been moved to [`urllib.request`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html), so use [`urllib.request.retrieve`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) and [`urllib.request.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlopen) respectively.

Comment: @AndréTerra good note, however the question is tagged `python-2.7`

Comment: -1: `f.write` doesn't accept `urlopen()`. You could use `shutil.copyfileobj(urllib2.urlopen(url), f)` instead.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it by passing there a string object returned from `.read()` method

Comment: I've removed the downvote. Though `copyfileobj` is better for large files then `.read()` that loads the whole file into memory

Comment: @Crystal I noticed it was tagged python 2.7, so that's why I added a comment instead of a response ;) I figured many Python 3 developers will still land here after searching on Google or here on SO, and in the long term, we'll all be using Python 3.