# What is the significance of 1024 when downloading chunks?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was looking for a post on downloading large files using `urllib` and came across a post ([Stream large binary files with urllib2 to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517616/stream-large-binary-files-with-urllib2-to-file)) with an answer by @AlexMartelli that showed the following:

```
chunk = 16 * 1024
```

I know that 1024 bytes = 1 KiB(KB) by the IEC standard. Does this mean that it will try to download my file in 16 separate 1024 byte "chunks"?

Comment: From what I see it seems that the size of the chunk is what is given in the `CHUNK` variable... So that means that whatever size the file is, it will be read by chunks of 16Kbits.

Comment: That is a misleading statement there, the original code is `chunk = response.read(CHUNK)` as per the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517728/206367) supplied suggests the chunk size of 16 times 1024 which equates to reading a chunk of data that is potentially maximum of 16384 K per read operation.

Comment: @t0mm13b Isnt that the same as saying it will read it in ~16MB chunks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it means that the person is defining a chunk of 16K units of memory and data will be downloaded in units of 16K memory

Answer (score 0):

No, it means that it will try to download the file in one or more 16kiB chunks, since there will only be one number in the end.