# Robot Framework urlopen option

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm using robot framework as a testing framework. one of my usecases is to upload a zip file using POST request.

I created the right command for uploading a local file, it works perfectly.
However, I want to take it to a bit more flexible approach.

Instead of download the file to my computer and uploading it, I want to give a URL with holds the file I'm about to upload.

Meaning, giving it the url `http://X.X.X.X/test.zip`.

My main problem is that I need to figure out a way to read the binary chunk and send it to the API.

In python it's easy doing it with using urlopen ([Stream large binary files with urllib2 to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517616/stream-large-binary-files-with-urllib2-to-file)), but I didn't found any way of doing it in robot.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you already know how to do it in Python, then you could just as well write your own library to do it. Just check out the [Creating Test Libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#id216) section of the user guide.

Comment: I agree that it can be done.
However, I'm into using same library convention and not repacking something from scratch..