# Google cloud storage signed url chunked download In python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

I'd like to do the following functionality:

```
  service = get_service('storage', 'v1', auth)

  data = BytesIO()
  request = service.objects().get_media(bucket=bucket, object=filename)
  media = MediaIoBaseDownload(data, request, chunksize=chunksize)
```

But with a signed URL instead if a bucket and object.  How do I chunk download a signed url in python?

Answer (score 0):

You can create s Signed URL either [using gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-gsutil) or writing your [own code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/create-signed-urls-program) to generate it. I have tested it using this:

```
gsutil signurl -d 10m my-key-file.json gs://my-bucket-name/my-file
```

After that the problem reduces to:

```
import urllib2
response = urllib2.urlopen('https://storage.googleapis.com/etc...')
html = response.read()
```

Or maybe:

```
from six.moves import urllib
urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://storage.goo.../etc","my-file")
print("File downloaded")
```

as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22682/9015852).

There's also a [repo](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/storage-signedurls-python) where they have developed code to generate signed urls using python.

Answer (score 0):

Signed URLs are just regular downloads, no need for special cloud APIS, and can be downloaded using a urllib read function answered here:

[Stream large binary files with urllib2 to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517616/stream-large-binary-files-with-urllib2-to-file)