# requests.get on large file, incomplete download but can't find indication of error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm trying to use requests to download a large file (namely an android cts zip file) using [the same technique as this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16696317/1013719). **Intermittently** it is failing to download the whole file, but I can't find any indication that something has gone wrong until I try to unzip the file

```
CTS_URL = 'http://dl.google.com/dl/android/cts/android-cts-8.0_r14-linux_x86-x86.zip'
CTS_ZIP = 'android-cts-8.0_r14-linux_x86-x86.zip'

import requests

req = requests.get(CTS_URL, stream=True)
with open(CTS_ZIP, 'wb') as cts_zip_file:
  for chunk in req.iter_content(chunk_size=4096):
    cts_zip_file.write(chunk)
```

later when I try to unzip I'm getting a `BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")` error, because the file hasn't been fully-downloaded

```
import zipfile
zipfile.ZipFile(CTS_ZIP)  # fails
```

However, I can't get any indication from the request object that something has gone wrong. `req.status` is `200`, `req.ok` is `True`.

Does `req` know that something went wrong? I currently have one of these request objects in an interactive prompt so I can inspect it further.

Comment: You can manually check `Content-length`. If it doesn't match file's size, that is wrong.

Comment: it is strange , i did not get any errors with your code.

Comment: Whats your download speed and latency? If it's slow and header `Connection`  doesn't set as `Connection: Keep-Alive`, and the `Keep-Alive` header field has Keep-Alive with low timeout, then there could be chance that the webserver closes the connection to you

Comment: I face the same problem and there is no solution now. Have you resolved this problem ?

Comment: @W.Dan I checked the `Content-length` and redid the request if the file size didn't match

Comment: @RyanHaining I finally found a workaround solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67053532/9265663

Comment: This is `requests` issue [#4956](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/4956).

Answer (score 0):

The code you share worked for me. However, you might consider about following things:

1. Like sraw mentioned, check `Content-length` value.
2. Check the file you downloaded. If the size of file is correct, you can try to extract the file manually in shell (just wanted to make sure).
3. You can try to use urllib ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517728/2055690))
4. It could be also server problem as well -- just in case. You can try to download different file.