# 64k limit on json data for urlopen

Tags: python, urllib

Banging my head on a problem. I will caveat in advance that is not reproducible since I cannot share my end point. Also I work as a data scientist, so my knowledge of web technologies is limited.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

url = "https://www.some_endpoint.com/"
req = Request(
    url, headers={"API-TOKEN": "some_token"})
json_string = "{"object": "XYZ".....}"

response = urlopen(req, json_string.encode("utf-8"))
```

I am getting unusual behavior on the urlopen. When my JSON is below 65536 bytes, as shown by evaluating `len(json_string.encode('utf-8'))`, this urlopen call works fine. When it is over that limit, I get an `HTTP 500` error.

Is this purely a server side error limitation on sizing? What is unusual is that when the large data is passed through a GUI to the endpoint, it works fine. Or is there something I can do to chunk my data to sub 64k bytes on the urlopen? Are there industry standards for handling this?

Comment: It depends on the server. I would suggest switching to the Requests library (http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) anyway, to make things easier for you.

Comment: Have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1517728/4288043

Comment: just tried with requests. same problem. server side then?

Comment: HTTP 500 is server side range code, so yes

Comment: Someone said "64k should be enough for anyone" :) Just google this sentence.

Comment: its actually 640k not 64k! hah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTP 500 error indicates an "internal server error". In theory, this means that there is not a problem with your code, there is a problem with the server.

In practice, an HTTP 500 error can mean almost anything, because many servers will use HTTP 500 as the default error code when a more specific error code is not provided by the programmer. Unfortunately, this means you are reduced to making guesses at how somebody else's code works.

Here are some possible approaches:

- It's possible that the server has a maximum request size of 64 KiB. You can reduce your request size by using more compact JSON (remove spaces between delimiters) or by using `Content-Encoding: gzip`.

  ```
  import gzip
  import json

  # Remove whitespace from JSON
  json_string = json.dumps(
      json.loads(json_string),
      separators=(',', ':'))
  # Encode as Gzip
  json_data = gzip.compress(
      json_string.encode('UTF-8'))

  req = Request(
      url, headers={"API-TOKEN": "some_token",
                    "Content-Encoding": "gzip"})
  response = urlopen(req, json_data)
  ```
- It's possible that there is some way of splitting or chunking the request into multiple, smaller requests. This would require knowledge of the exact API you are using.
- It's possible that there's some bug in the server or a proxy somewhere in the chain that prevents you from sending the request as written. You could try using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, if `Content-Length` does not work for >64 KiB. It's possible the server expects to use 100 Continue, but `urllib` does not support this.

If you MITM your GUI client with a tools like Charles, you can see the exact format of the request and you can make your own request use the same format.

Comment: thanks for the answer. tried gzip, transfer-encoding; no luck. i will just split on my end locally.